# rails sorting and searching simultaneously

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting

I have implemented search functionality for my index page .
I am using

```
 helper_method :sort_column, :sort_direction

def sort_column
  SyuhoArea.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : "syuhoid"
end

def sort_direction
  %w[asc desc].include?(params[:direction]) ? params[:direction] : "desc"
end
```

for sorting.
Now , the issuse is whenever i click for sorting the page gets reload and because of that the search textboxes are cleared .

i want to search textboxes to hold their values while sorting.
Is there any way that i can pass search textbox values as a params while params[:sort] and params[:direction] are passed to controller.

For this i made custom link hard coded link in view.

before it was like

```
  <th class="text-center"><%= sortable "dept_id", "dept_id" %> </th>
```

now i have made it to

```
  <th class="text-center asc">
  <a class="current asc" href="/syuho_honbus?direction=asc&amp;sort=dept_id;dept_id=<%= params[:dept_id]%>;status=<%= params[:status]%>;created_at=<%= params[:created_at]%>">状況</a> </th>
```

But now it only gets sorted in ascending order.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, use an instance '@' variable to pass the your search textbox values.  In your form, use the same variable, and since its populated, it'll show in your view.  In your initial viewing of the page, the variable will be nil so it will be blank.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
helper_method :sort_column, :sort_direction

    def sort_column
      @sort_column ||= SyuhoArea.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : "syuhoid"
    end

    def sort_direction
      @sort_direction ||= %w[asc desc].include?(params[:direction]) ? params[:direction] : "desc"
    end
```